# Can i iterate over a database to produce views from many tables at once?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostGIS database with several tables with foreign key related to one table that holds the primary key. I have to apply certain select ..to each one of these tables, can I loop over the primary key table to get it done?
Can this be done without even use the primary-foreign key relation? 
I can't find any information on iterating inside a database, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way to execute a query across multiple tables in Postgres is to use join statements. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html

Executing multiple queries, one for each table, and then, within your application logic, aggregating the results and then iterating over the aggregation to implement, for example, a `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` statement will always be less efficient than using a single query.

Setting indexes on the foreign keys of the tables you are joining will greatly improve the performance of the query. You can also improve query performance by scaling up the CPU and RAM over your server or by using something like Citus to horizontally scale your database across multiple servers.

Comment: if I understand correctly you mean joining every table of interest and applying the query selecting by attribute? I don't think that is such a good idea since each table has between 20-50 thousand rows, and the query is slow enough as they are now.